# Unable to make a really basic sketch work

Tags: button, input, pull-up

I've been learning how to encapsulate my code within functions, and one of the examples I worked on is a simple INPUT_PULLUP button. When I upload the sketch from the [arduino website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/InputPullupSerial) everything works, so I know it's not a hardware issue. However, with the code below the button will just not go LOW.

I just don't see what the issue is, and I'm feeling really hopeless that I can't even get the simple thing done. I would be grateful for any advice.

```
int button_pin = 2;
int button_state = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(button_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  Button();
}

void Button() {
  // Read button(s)
  button_state = digitalRead(button_pin);
  if (button_state = LOW) {
    Serial.println(button_state);
  };
};
```

Comment: You have an error in the if statement. For checking equality, you need to use `==` (double equal sign). A single `=` is an assignment. So you are actually assigning the value LOW to `button_state`. And an assignment will return the value, that you assigned, in this case LOW, aka 0, aka false. Thus the if statement will never be entered

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will try this and report. I don't know what I would do without you people. I wasted several hours on this yesterday trying everything I could think of with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define button_pin 2  //defining button pin as pin 2
bool button_state = 0; //button state is either 0/1 so using bool
void Button();
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(button_pin, INPUT_PULLUP); //Setting input as input pullup
}

void loop()
{
    Button();
}

void Button()
{
    
    button_state = digitalRead(button_pin); //Read button state
    if (button_state == LOW)
    {
        Serial.println(button_state); //print button state when it is low
    }
}
```

In your code, you have used `=` operator in place of `==` in the if loop. Just if you change it, it will start working also you can use my above code it is same as yours just I have made some minor changes such as using `bool` in place of int and use of `#define` in place of pin declaration where you used `int`

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. It's really helpful and I appreciate it.

Comment: @ZhelyazkoGrudov I am glad it helped you out. Good luck :)